# Wordpress PHP Snippet to redirect link to another link

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to redirect a custom url to another custom url in the website using a php snippet without .htaccess

I tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
add_filter('get_the_permalink','my_permalink_redirect');
function my_permalink_redirect($permalink) {
    global $post;
    if ($permalink = 'https://www.staging2.domain.com/shop/') {
        $permalink = 'https://www.staging2.domain.com/event/';
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most glamorous way to do it, but you could try echoing JS that does the redirect.

```
function redirect_from_shop() {

        echo "<script>
               var pagePath = window.location.pathname;

                if (pagePath == '/shop/') {

                window.location = 'https://www.staging2.domain.com/event/'; 
                } 

              </script>";


}
add_action('wp_head', 'redirect_from_shop');
```

Comment: It worked fine, but does that make any loop or affect the site performance or use many resources or it just fires only once each time a user tries to access the shop page only if user tried to access the shop page ?

Comment: Only runs if someone visits the shop page.  No does not require a lot of resources.  Just a simple piece of javascript. Ultimately, if you want to run JS on certain pages, it's better practice to use wp_enqueue.  But this is a simple way to get things working the way you want.

Comment: Thank you indeed for your help, so it only runs if someone visited the shop page only not visiting any page it runs, thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `template_redirect` action and `wp_redirect` to do this.

`template_redirect` fires right before the template is loaded, so you can check to see if WordPress is about to load the page you want to redirect from, and if it is, redirect to the new page.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {
    // is_page takes a Page ID, title, slug, or array as a parameter
    if ( is_page( 'shop' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://www.staging2.tktshub.com/event/' );
        die();
    }
} );
```

Comment: I have tested this solution and added the snippet but its not working you can even test with the url now, i'm already adding the snippet now

Comment: Do you know what version of php your server is running? If its less than 5.3 that code wouldn't work because closures aren't available.

Comment: I know the version that is running but i double checked too its 7.1